# github python file not running on heroku praw not installing?

Tags: python, heroku, bots, reddit, praw

I made the python file with praw and I am trying to upload the .py file to github then use Heroku to execute the app.

I keep getting an error from Heroku that it cannot find praw. I have it set in the file to download and import it, but it's not working?

```
   pip install praw
    import praw

   previous_id="0"
    
  reddit = praw.Reddit(    
       user_agent="by u/Sam-Kinison-Bot",
       client_id="xxx",
       client_secret="xxx",
       username="Sam-Kinison-Bot",
       password="xxx",)

    previous_id="0"

    def search():
     for results in reddit.subreddit('all').comments():
        global previous_id  
    
    body = results.body  
    body=body.lower()   
    comment_id = results.id  
    
    if comment_id == previous_id: 
        return "Error"
    

    
    found=body.find('. it is a joke.')  
        
    if found != -1:         
        previous_id = comment_id  
        
        try:
            results.reply('CAUSE IT IS A JOKE OHHH OHHH OHHHHHHHHHHHHH')    
        except:
            break
```

and the error message i get on herkou when trying to deploy:

```
     Obtaining file:///tmp/build_d6ccc43e (from -r 
     /tmp/build_d6ccc43e/requirements.txt (line 1))
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
       sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/build_d6ccc43e/setup.py'"'"'; 
     __file__='"'"'/tmp/build_d6ccc43e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
      '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
      '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info 
      --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b6erccd7
            cwd: /tmp/build_d6ccc43e/
       Complete output (6 lines):
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
         File "/tmp/build_d6ccc43e/setup.py", line 1
           pip install praw
               ^
       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the 
   logs for full command output.
    !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    !     Push failed
```

Any tips to point me in the right direction? Should I just throw it all away and start new?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run pip like that from inside a python script.

Pip is a shell command. You need to specify your dependencies somewhere else.

I think that if you include your dependencies in a requirements.txt file in the root of your repository, heroku will install them for you. Read about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip).

So in your case something like that

requirements.txt

```
praw==7.4.0
```

If you want to know your current dependencies in your development environment type this in your shell to know what to include to your requirements.txt file.

```
pip freeze
```